# Mirroring - Server network address cannot be reached

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, mirroring

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 Installed. It contains three instances.

1. Default (MSSQLServer)
2. First Instance
3. Second Instance

All these are Log On as Network Service..

Default Instance is Principal server
First Instance is Mirror
Second Instance is Witness Server

I initially took the Full Backup and Transactional Log Backup of my Principal Database.
Restored it to the First Instance by keeping the same Database Name and Recovery State is No-Recovery

Finally, I started the Mirroring and I am getting two error messages shown below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Try some basic connectivity tests.

1. Verify that 5022, 5023 and 5024 are listening.
2. Verify that the server name you are using is correct.

From the command line :

```
netstat -an
```

[image]

On my server, you can see that 5022 is listening.

Next make sure that you can connect to those ports via telnet

```
telnet fully-qualified-server-name 5022
```

As it mentions in the **Note** section of the Mirroring Properties GUI, just below the witness field, the server names have to be fully qualified tcp addresses.

[image]

You should just see a black screen.  In this example I chose a name that would cause a connection failure.  If you see "Could not open connection", then the server(s) defined as mirror, principal and witness aren't reachable or you are not using the right name.

The telnet client can be added under Features in Windows 2008.

In Windows 2008, when you right click on Computer, you can see the full computer name. 
You should be able to ping it as well from the command line.  ex: ping myservername

**Update**

Please run the following queries on each SQL Server instance and put the results in your question.  Many of these troubleshooting tips come from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189127.aspx

**Show tcp endpoints**

```
SELECT type_desc, port FROM sys.tcp_endpoints;
```

**Display status of mirroring endpoints**

```
SELECT state_desc FROM sys.database_mirroring_endpoints;
```

**Check that the ROLE is correct**

```
SELECT role FROM sys.database_mirroring_endpoints;
```

**Display permissions to endpoints**

```
SELECT EP.name, SP.STATE, 
   CONVERT(nvarchar(38), suser_name(SP.grantor_principal_id)) 
      AS GRANTOR, 
   SP.TYPE AS PERMISSION,
   CONVERT(nvarchar(46),suser_name(SP.grantee_principal_id)) 
      AS GRANTEE 
   FROM sys.server_permissions SP , sys.endpoints EP
   WHERE SP.major_id = EP.endpoint_id
   ORDER BY Permission,grantor, grantee; 
GO
```

The login for the service account from the other server instance requires CONNECT permission. Make sure that the login from the other server has CONNECT permission. To determine who has CONNECT permission for an endpoint, on each server instance use the following Transact-SQL statement.

Example output:

```
name    STATE   GRANTOR PERMISSION  GRANTEE
TSQL Local Machine  G   sqladmin    CO      public
TSQL Named Pipes    G   sqladmin    CO      public
TSQL Default TCP    G   sqladmin    CO      public
TSQL Default VIA    G   sqladmin    CO      public
Mirroring   G   SERVERNAME\Grantor  CO      SERVERNAME\Grantee
```

Grantor is the account that assigned (CO) connect permission, Grantee is the account that has connect permission

From the command line run `ipconfig /all` and note what Host Name returns.